# Hello i am having an error while trying to run my first app on android studio

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-emulator

Below is my error message please i need help

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Beejay\first_app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.
      > Could not generate a decorated class for type AppPlugin.
         > com/android/utils/ILogger
```

i was expecting to have the app run on my emulator

Answer (score 0):

First, in your project:

- Open `android/build.gadle` file
- Search for `com.android.tools.build:gradle`, it's something like this:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        ...
    }
}
```

- change the version of it to an older version

Refer to this to see versions, [Android Gradle plugin release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle)